# How to replace ~ with actual home path in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a few files which needed to be backed up from multiple directories. Few of the files are from the `home` directory. For example, I need to back up the `~/.ssh/config` file. There are multiple files that have to be backed up. The array of files looked like something below.

`array=("~/.bash_aliases" "~/.bashrc" "~/.ssh/config" "~/.ssh/set_git_profile.sh")`

I looped the array using the `for...do...done` loop. However, each item in the array was a string and I was unable to resolve `~` with the actual path. For example, `~` to be replaced with `/home/<user>` in all the file names.

The Final array should look like something below for the user called `rahul`

`array=("/home/rahul/.bash_aliases" "/home/rahul/.bashrc" "/home/rahul/.ssh/config" "/home/rahul/.ssh/set_git_profile.sh")`

Comment: Don't. `'~'` will not be resolved inside a script, use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries and searches, I could not resolve the `~` on the fly, i.e., in the execution of the script. However, there is an easy way of doing this, i.e., using the `$HOME` shell variable. The `$HOME` points to the home path of the user. So, finally, I used the below array of files.

`array=("${HOME}/.bash_aliases" "${HOME}/.bashrc" "${HOME}/.ssh/config" "${HOME}/.ssh/set_git_profile.sh")`